# Filter first value of column when values are seperated by commas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   col1  col2   col3
0  a     a,b,c  c,b,a
1  b     c,a,b  b,c,a
2  c     b,c,a  a,c,b
```

I would like to create a new df that contains col1 with first values of col2 and col3.

So the new df would look like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  a     a     c
1  b     c     b
2  c     b     a
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following once, written and tested with shown samples.

```
df=df.apply(lambda x : x.str.replace(",.*", ""))
```

When we print `df` output will be as follows.

```
    col1 col2 col3
0   a   a   c
1   b   c   b
2   c   b   a
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
df = df.apply(lambda x : x.str[0])
# if more character, you can try split 
# df = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split(',').str[0])
Out[43]: 
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    a    c
1    b    c    b
2    c    b    a
```

Comment: In the comment did you mean `lambda x : x.str.split(',')` ?